# SendMessage to a menu of a child window integrated in the main window

Tags: vba, automation

Im triying to use this same methodology:

```
'lhWndP is the main window
menu = GetMenu(lhWndP)
menu_file = GetSubMenu(menu, 0)
menu_file_open = GetMenuItemID(menu_file, 1)
SendMessage lhWndP, WM_COMMAND, menu_file_open, 0
```

With a child window (of WindowsForms10.Window.8 type) that is integrated in the main window:

```
'lhWndP is the main window
lhWndP = FindWindowEx(lhWndP, 0&, "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.235679a", "menustrip")
'lhWndP, now the child window, returns a correct handle
menu = GetMenu(lhWndP)
'getmenu returns the same handle of lhWndP, then getsubmenu returns 0
menu_file = GetSubMenu(menu, 0)
menu_file_open = GetMenuItemID(menu_file, 1)
SendMessage lhWndP, WM_COMMAND, menu_file_open, 0
```

I think I can't apply getmenu method with child windows.

Any ideas to figure out a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an MDI application?  It's possible that the menu is implemented with a `CMFCMenuBar` instead of a `CMenu*`. See the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983676.aspx).